# How to set the value and item checked of a listpreference in an onchangelistener

Tags: android, kotlin, preference, listpreference

I'm having problems updating the value of a `ListPreference`.
`ListPreference.setDefaultValue()` and `ListPreference.setIndexValue()` don't seem to be recognized methods.

I want to "reset" all other `ListPreference`s when one of their buddy `ListPreference`s are clicked, so that only one of them has a valid value at any given time.

Also, the `android:defaultValue="1"` in the XML file doesn't seem to work either, at least not in view. 
Does this only change the actual value? Does it not check the first value as well?

The `ListPreference`s are behaving like they should other than that, so I'm sure the xml files are good. 
I'm using androidx, I have implemented `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0`

```
Class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  Class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onPreferenceCreated() {
      setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs)
    }

    fun onCreate(savedInstances) {
      val listPreference1 = findPreference(listpreference1)
      val listPreference2 = findPreference(listpreference2)

      listPreference1.setOnChangeListener { preference: Preference, newValue: Any ->

      //listPreference2.         <---- This is where the expected methods aren't showing. Not setDefaultValue, setValue, setIndexValue.

      true ^setOnchangeListener
    }
  }
}
```

I don't actually get to the results as I can't use the method that I need.

If you need any other information I'll try to provide more.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`findPreference(String)` is the correct method for retrieving a reference to your `ListPreference`s. The problem is that it returns a variable of type `Preference`, which is the base class for all UI settings components. 
If you need to access features that are only available to `ListPreference`, and you are sure that that preference is a `ListPreference` (i.e., it is defined as a `ListPreference` in your XML file), you can safely cast it :

```
val listPreference1 = findPreference("my_list_preference_1") as ListPreference
```

This way, you should be able to use methods that are specific to `ListPreference` :

```
listPreference1.setValue("Whatever you'd like")
```

Note that this is not specific to Kotlin, this is how Object-Oriented Programming works : you can only call methods on a object that are defined by its interface. If you want to call methods of a subclass, you need to make the assertion that this object is an instance of that subclass (that's what we call a "cast", done with the `as` syntax in Kotlin).

Also, I suggest that you call `findPreference` in `onCreatePreferences`, after `setPreferencesFromResources(R.xml.prefs)`, otherwise you'll likeky get a `NullPointerException`.